# Custom-post template won't work

Tags: php, wordpress

I've created a custom post type. I also have single-projects.php but for some reason the custom post won't use the template. I've tried to flush the permalinks. 
I'm using the Themefortress Reverie Theme.

```
class projects_post_type {

function projects_post_type() {
    add_action('init',array($this,'create_post_type'));
}

function create_post_type() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'Projects',
        'singular_name' => 'Project',
        'add_new' => 'Add new',
        'all_items' => 'All Projects',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add New Project',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Project',
        'new_item' => 'New Project',
        'view_item' => 'View Project',
        'search_items' => 'Search Project',
        'not_found' =>  'No Projects found',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Projects found in trash',
        'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent Project:',
        'menu_name' => 'Projects'
    );
    $args = array(
        'taxonomies' => array('category','post_tag'),
        'labels' => $labels,
        'description' => "All Consplan Projects",
        'public' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true, 
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true, 
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'menu_icon' => null,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail','excerpt','custom-fields'),
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'projects', 'with_front' => false),
        'query_var' => true,
        'can_export' => true
    ); 
    register_post_type('projects_post_type',$args);
}
}

$projects_post_type = new projects_post_type();

?>
```

Comment: Is this your original code? or just an example?

Comment: the orginal code I'm using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your mistake `register_post_type('projects_post_type',$args);`

The post type of your custom post type is `projects_post_type` not `projects`.

You just declare `projects` as `slug` not as post type `key`

Replace:

```
register_post_type('projects_post_type',$args);
```

With this

```
register_post_type('projects',$args);
```

Then flush the permalinks again so changes can take effect.

`single-custom_post_type.php` which is `single-projects.php` should work now.